# when rebinding the grid view,losses the previously stored values in c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have grid view. when the page load event occurs the values in grid view are displayed properly.
But when i Tried to insert a new value to that data-table,its not working, only the inserted values are displaying not all the values in the data-table.
How to solve this?? My code:

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
        {
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT QuestionID,Options from QuestMultiChoice where QuestionID= '"+ labelID.Text +"'", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da1.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da1.Fill(TempDTable);
            gvDetails.DataSource = TempDTable;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
}

   protected void imgbtnAdd_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable TempDTable = new DataTable();

        if (ViewState["PdataTable1"] == null)
        {

            TempDTable.Columns.Add("QuestionID", typeof(string));
            TempDTable.Columns.Add("Options", typeof(string));
        }
        else
        {
            TempDTable = (DataTable)ViewState["PdataTable1"];
        }
        DataRow row = TempDTable.NewRow();
        TextBox txtftr = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftr");

        row["QuestionID"] = labelID.Text;
        row["Options"] = txtftr.Text;

        TempDTable.Rows.Add(row);
        //this.GridViewColumns.Visible = true;
        ViewState["PdataTable1"] = TempDTable;
        gvDetails.DataSource = TempDTable;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
    }
```

aspx code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" runat="server"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#61A6F8"
 ShowFooter="True" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
 onrowdeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" onrowcommand="gvDetails_RowCommand" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
        onselectedindexchanged="gvDetails_SelectedIndexChanged" 

        style="z-index: 1; left: 136px; top: 177px; position: absolute; height: 246px; width: 517px" 
        onrowediting="gvDetails_RowEditing" onrowupdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating">
<RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<EditItemTemplate>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAdd" runat="server" Height="30px" 
    ImageUrl="~/Images/add.jpg" OnClick="imgbtnAdd_Click1" ValidationGroup="five" 
    Width="30px" />
  </FooterTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
    Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblitemUsr" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Options") %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtftr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtftr" runat="server" Width="405px"/>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRowValue" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftr"    Text="*Enter Value" ValidationGroup="five"/>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>

<FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
```

Comment: If(!ISPostback){//your gridview binding code}..do this in your page load..

Comment: make datasource and binding in a seperate method and call it..because your data is not refershed.It retains old value.

Comment: Your are not inserting the data to the database. in button click you are just inserting that data into a temp data table and binding that data in to the gridview. So the gridview will show only the newly inserted record. the better parctise is, please write a new method to bind the grid from DB, and then on the button click insert data in to the DB, aftert that call the dinding method again.

Comment: i need to show all the inserted value in data-table.Then only the data will be saved in the db when the update Button pressed